# how to stream video from a camera connected to Raspberry Pi to a PC on the same network?

Tags: c++, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am going to connect:
a:  a wifi dongle to Raspberry Pi and make an Ad Hoc network
b:  a raspberry pi camera to the raspberry pi

I want to connect to the RPi's ad hoc network from my PC. Once the PC and the RPi are on the same network,an application on the PC should be able to stream video from the camera and be able to control the GPIO pins on the Raspberry. My problem is that I don't know how to get started with the application.
 Can anyone tell me what topics to read,and what libraries to use for streaming?anything that can help me at all will be highly appreciated as I am completely in the dark right now.I am comfortable with programming in C++ so the application will naturally be in C++.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a possible starting point for the video streaming could be mjpg-streamer
https://code.google.com/p/mjpg-streamer/

I used this without problem to stream video from the pi so that I could view it in a browser on a different PC on the same network.

Comment: ok I just read about mjpg streamer and it seems its just for streaming video to a browser,the problem is I want it to be part of an application which can also control the GPIO pins,how can I do that?

Comment: I guess something like this might be useful for controlling the GPIO pins: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=43725

Answer (score 0):

I did it before using mjpg-streamer and also made a video show the way to do.

Check it here

[Easiest way to stream Raspberry Pi Camera Module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUsaI3etYaU)